# Helper not recognizing the `htmlSafe` stuff

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to retun a value with space added through `helper`. but I am not getting the result.

here is my code :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function cardNoDisplay(params/*, hash*/) {
  var paramStr = params.toString(); 
  var updatedParams = paramStr.substring(paramStr.length-4);
  var reformat = paramStr.replace(/(\d{4})/g, function(match){
    return match + Ember.String.htmlSafe("<span>++</span>");
  });
  return reformat;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(cardNoDisplay);
```

But the result comes like :

```
<span>3230<span>++</span>4211<span>++</span>5712<span>++</span>8203<span>++</span></span>
```

What is wrong with my code here?

thanks in advance.

here is the HBS file :

```
<span class="cs2i-purchase-card-font">
                {{card.cardName}}
                <span>{{card-no-display card.cardNo}}</span>
              </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my filter as like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function cardNoDisplay(params/*, hash*/) {
  var paramStr = params.toString(); 
  var updatedParams = paramStr.substring(paramStr.length-4);
  var reformat = paramStr.replace(/(\d{4})/g, function(match){
    return match + "<span> </span>";
  });
  return Ember.String.htmlSafe(reformat);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(cardNoDisplay);
```

Works fine. thanks to `TBieniek`

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your snippet is that `htmlSafe()` only works for entire strings, not for just parts of a string. instead of applying `htmlSafe()` inside the regex replacement function you can `return Ember.String.htmlSafe(reformat)` and then it should work as expected.